# Flutter Null Safety Migration says `Package doesn't exist`

Tags: flutter, dart, migration, dart-null-safety

## Flutter Null Safety Migration

I am trying to migrate my project to Flutter Null Safety Version and I am following [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide) official migration guide.

When I run the second command it says
`Package doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available).`

### Command I ran

me@My-MacBook-Air my_project % `dart --version`
`Dart SDK version: 2.12.0 (stable) (Thu Feb 25 19:50:53 2021 +0100) on "macos_x64"`
me@My-MacBook-Air my_project % `dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety`
`Package doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not available).`

### Flutter Doctor Output

```
me@My-MacBook-Air my_project % `flutter doctor -v`
Flutter (Channel beta, 2.0.2, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.0.2 at /Users/me/flutter
    • Framework revision 8962f6dc68 (9 days ago), 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
    • Engine revision 5d8bf811b3
    • Dart version 2.12.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.17.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try `flutter pub outdated --mode=null-safety`, should display the the migration state of your package’s dependencies.

Comment: hello sir i tried your method flutter pub outdated --mode=null-safety , but this error appears :
Could not find an option named "mode".
can you help me why the error occurs

Comment: Hi @Jsoon, did you get the soultion ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see anything obvious here, the command is just a lookup you can still check all dependencies on pub.dev manual when all the packages support null safety and the other commands are working you should be fine.

I only have one idea the beta channel should be fine in most cases, but switch to stable if nothing works

```
flutter channel stable
```

make sure you run `flutter upgrade`

Comment: Thanks, In my case I can't switch to the stable channel because I am targeting desktop devices.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar okay, can you provide the list of packages you use

Answer (score -1):

First run:

```
dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
```

and to upgrade your packages to null-safe variant, run:

```
dart pub upgrade --null-safety
```